# how to read the json values with jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, dotnetnuke-6

my JSON response is like this `{ "items":[{"s": "2","f": "host","m": "hi..:)"}, ] }`

I wrote the following code to read the JSON data. but not getting the any value. alert box also not working. If any one please inform me where I did mistake ...

```
$.ajax({

    url: "ChatHandler.aspx?action=chatheartbeat",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

        $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {

            if (item) { // fix strange ie bug

                chatboxtitle = item.f;

                alert(item.m);

            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(item[0].m);
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/V8kJE/)

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
alert(data.items[i].m)
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V8kJE/1/) here

Comment: i am not getting any error.i am using firebug to check the json the data .Following output i am getting { "items":[{"s": "2","f": "host","m": "hi..:)"}, ] }

Comment: but in my jquery i used the above code i am not getting the values in jquery.thats is the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
    if (item) {
        alert(i);//alerts 0 - the index of the first item
        var s = item.s
        var f = item.f
        var m = item.m;
       alert(f);// alerts "host"
    }
});
```

the "strange ie bug" is due to the fact that you have an EMPTY object (see that last comma in the array :)  That second item is "undefined" in your data set